# PHP Session variables disappearing on new page

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have been trying to figure out this issue I am having with PHP and Session cookies. For some reason, when I go to a new page within the same server, the sesion variable is not populating, but the session_id() is. And then if I go back and log back in, it works?? I have tried a few links on here and googled around, but nothing seems to work.

```
class SessionRepository
{

public $errors;

public function StartSession()
{
session_start();
}

public function SetUserSession($userName,$fullName)
{
        // Start session
        $this->StartSession;

        // Make sure there isn't something already set
        /*if (isset($_SESSION['userName']))
            unset($_SESSION['userName']);
        */
        // Make sure there isn't something already set
        /*if (isset($_SESSION['fullName']))
            unset($_SESSION['fullName']);
*/
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
        $_SESSION['fullName'] = $fullName;


}

public function CheckLogin($userName)
{
        $this->StartSession;
        if(empty($_SESSION[$userName]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}

public function DestroyUserSession()
{
    $this->StartSession;

    session_destroy();
}

}






include("useritemrepository.php");
include('UserItem.php');
include('sessionrepository.php');
include('login.php');

if(!isset($_POST['submitcreds']))
{
    LoginPage($loginerror);
}
else
{


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
        $userName = $_POST["userName"];
        $password = md5($_POST["password"]);

        $session = new SessionRepository();
        $userRepository = new UserItemRepository();

        $loggedin = $userRepository->LoginUser($userName,$password);

        if($userRepository->errors !="")
                    echo $userRepository->errors;

        if ($loggedin->UserName =="")
        {
            $loginerror = "Invald Credentials, Please try again";

            LoginPage($loginerror);
        }
        else
        {
        $fullName = $loggedin->FirstName . " " . $loggedin->LastName;

        // Build Session 
        $session->SetUserSession($userName,$fullName);
        echo "Session:" . $_SESSION["fullName"] ." ". $_SESSION["userName"];
        LoggedIn();
        exit();
        }

    }
    }
```

Then Here is the login page (login.php)

```
session_start();
function LoginPage($loginerror)
{

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>
        Cold Calling Center
        </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='site.css'/>
        </head>

        <body>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper" width="600px" height="600px">
        <form name="login" action="<? $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
        <span id="login-header" class="login-header"><? echo $loginerror;?></span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <span id="header">Welcome to Cold Calling Central</span>

        <table id="login-table">
        <th id="table-header">Login Form</th>
        <tr id="login-row">
        <td id="login-cell">UserName:</td>
        <td id="login-cell"><input type="text" name="userName"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="login-row">
        <td id="login-cell">Password:</td>
        <td id="login-cell"><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="login-row">
        <td id="login-cell"><input type="submit" name="submitcreds" value="Login"/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="login-table">
        <td id="login-row"><a href="forgotPassword.php">Forgot Password</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="login-table">
        <td id="login-row"><a href="register.php">Not Registered?</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="PHP_AUTH_USER"/>

        </form>
        </div>

        </body>

        </html>
 }

function RedirectToPage()
{
$url ="loggedin.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
      CONTENT="1; URL=<? 
      /*Redirect user to their page upon update */
      echo $url;?>">
<title>Thank you for logging in</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="briefing.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="shadow">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="branding"></div> 
<div id="content">

<h2></h2>


<table class="briefing" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h4>Thank you for logging in <? echo $_SESSION['fullName'];?>.. you are now being redirected to your page!</h4></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>



</table>


</div>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?
}

function LoggedIn()
{?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tclassy for Linux (vers 6 November 2007), see www.w3.org">
<title>Registration</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='site.css' type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
        <span id="login-header" class="login-header"><? echo "Welcome: " . $_SESSION['fullName']; ?></span>

                <ul id="menu-List" class="menu-list">
                <li class="list-item"><a class="menu-link" href="loggedin.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a class="menu-link" href="test.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a class="menu-link" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a class="menu-link" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
}
```

And here is the page off of one of the links in the landing page. When I use the link to go to test.php, (the code below, it does not carry the Fullname session, but if I go back and login again, it works?

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "Name: " . $_SESSION["fullName"];
```

Comment: thats just giving me That just gave me  Array ( ) ... then if I refresh.. i get the full name

Comment: Both pages should have `session_start()`, I didn't see one on the first code snippet.

Comment: $session->SetUserSession($userName,$fullName); calls session_start()... I will add that file above

Comment: Did you mean to call `$this->StartSession()` instead of `$this->StartSession` in your class methods?

Comment: Yes Phoenix.. thank you Mike said the same thing below, it has been fixed, but still same issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put 
session_start();
*always* at the very top of your page!

so here it will probably work:

```
   <?
    session_start();
    include("useritemrepository.php");
    include('UserItem.php');
    include('sessionrepository.php');
    include('login.php');
    ...
```

because: if there is a single space outside of  (or more) in the other files you include. Session_start will not work. This space will be written to the output and session_start can not modify the http header of the page. Usually you get an error/warning/notice when that happens. So enable your errors or  look for the error-logfile. Since you are starting -> put the warnings and errors in the output and make shure you disable them when you deploy.

in essence 3 pieces of adivce:

1. session_start always goes first
2. no html in functions/classes
3. get the html out of your code and include "html/login.php" by using small variables

Comment: "Wow you just start with php" unnessesary comment. Actually what I have done above an't bad for not touching the stuff in a few years, so try not to judge. Like I show in the test.php, I do have session_start() in there session_start(); 
echo session_id(); 
echo "Name: " . $_SESSION["fullName"];

Comment: Sorry about that, but you may have some space in any of the files before session_start or a BOM in you utf-8 encoded files ?

Answer (score 1):

If your code paste is correct,  you have an error:

```
public function SetUserSession($userName,$fullName)
{
    // Start session
    $this->StartSession;

    // Should be
    $this->StartSession();
```

-- Update --

```
// landing page
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'I am hax0r';

// test page
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['test']); // Should output 'I am hax0r'
```

Comment: Thank you.. I fixed it... now to $this->StartSession();... but it still is doing the same thing. I login .. it doesn't work on the new page, go back to the last page, refresh and click the link again and it works

Comment: On the first page you are wrapping the `session_start` within the `SessionRepository::StartSession` function, which isn't called on the first page unless something was $_POSTed, I suggest adding `session_start()` before your includes on page one, and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks @mike... just tried that.. same thing?.. session_start();
 include("useritemrepository.php");
 include('UserItem.php');
 include('sessionrepository.php');
 include('login.php');

Comment: In your OP you stated "For some reason, when I go to a new page within the same server, the sesion variable is not populating, but the session_id() is", this is because, as I mentioned previously, the SessionRepository class is only be called if there is a POST, if there is no POST, then the `username` and `fullname` values will not be populated in the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: ok.. I get that, but the use case is that the "going to the new page" is after the login process. I will try setting it outside of the Post, but i don't think it will be any better

Comment: to prove the concept, I just added a tets session to the top of the form before anything happens. session_start();
 include("useritemrepository.php");
 include('UserItem.php');
 include('sessionrepository.php');
 include('login.php');
 $_SESSION["Test"] = "Gregg"; Then I did the log in process and tried to go to test.php and the new Session still does not work

Comment: session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "Name: " . $_SESSION["fullName"];
print_r($_SESSION["fullName"]); 
print_r($_SESSION["Test"]); This is test.php

Comment: I updated post, lets just make sure the basic functionality works before making it more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at

```
public function CheckLogin($userName)
{
        $this->StartSession;
        if(empty($_SESSION[$userName]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

I think it should read:

```
public function CheckLogin($userName)
{
        $this->StartSession;
        if(empty($_SESSION['userName']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```